# How to use a DataTable with an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable

I'm trying to use the property "data" to show my data in the table, but the table doesn't works. I made a test using a local array of strings and works very well, I don't know why with an object the table doesn't works

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {

  this.listarNotificacao()

  $('#datatables').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    lengthChange: false,
    responsive: true,
    searching: true,
    data: this.notificacoes,
    columns: [{
        data: 'guidNotificacao'
      },
      {
        data: 'titulo'
      },
      {
        data: 'descricao'
      },
      {
        data: 'escopo'
      },
    ],
    language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Pesquisar promoções",
      },
    }

  });

  const table = $('#datatables').DataTable();

  $('#inputSearch').on('keyup', function() {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="material-datatables">
  <table id="datatables" class="table  table-no-bordered " cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Título</th>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Escopo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you have an extra `}`

Comment: ```const table = $('#datatables').DataTable();``` does not need to be there. Assign ```table``` the previous datatable object you built.

Comment: You're instantiating your datatable twice, as @nullptr.t says.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your datatable initialization. There's an extra curly brace after language. If you look at your browser's dev console, it would have told you this.